# Which input block is used in Matlab simulink that provide random values with time?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am a new user of Matlab Simulink and currently i am working with Fuzzy Logic Controller with Simulation. In the Simulink, i want to input the values(i highlighted in the picture below), that changes with time.
[image]
Here, i am using Uniform Random Number Block which sends four values(which i feed) at same time but i want one value must input first, then another and so on. My target is to use Scope block(the one which is highlighted in the right side) and check the output that varies with time. But with current configuration, i just input ONLY one value. Please help?

Comment: Are any of the parameters of the Uniform Random Number Block a vector of size 4. This will make the output size 4. All parameters need to be scalar if you want a scalar output.

Comment: At first time, I input vector size of 4, but it input four of them at same time. But i want that every value can be input one at a time..Do you mean that if i replace Constant Blocks with Uniform Random Number block and all input are of same size then it can input one at a time???

Comment: Can you turn on signal sizes in the model and post that picture? You can display signal sizes using options from Display menu.